# Рассердиться на шутку / рассержен шуткой

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Как будет правильно:
"рассержен глупой выходкой", "рассержен на глупую выходку" или "рассержен глупой выходке"?

"Рассердиться неуместной шутке", "рассердиться на неуместную шутку" или "рассердиться неуместной шуткой"?

Answer (score 2):

[**Рассердиться**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?all=x&word=%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F), **на кого-что.** Почувствовать раздражение, негодование, гнев. *Сильно рассердиться. Рассердиться на родных, близких. Рассердиться на весь класс. Бабушка рассердилась на внука.*

Управление в русском языке:
РАССЕРДИТЬСЯ **на кого-что**. Рассердиться на соседей; Рассердиться на неуместную шутку. Сравнить: *рассерженный **чем.***

Вот что пишет Розенталь:
Следует различать конструкции со словами, близкими по значению или однокоренными, но требующими различного управления:
рассердиться **на кого-что** — рассержен **кем-чем** (*рассердился **на** неуместную **шутку** — рассержен глупой **выходкой***).

[§ 202. Управление при синонимических словах](http://rozental.gramatik.ru/xlv-upravlenie/ss-202-upravlenie-pri-sinonimicheskih-slovah)
[Управление в русском языке](https://books.google.ee/books?id=d5e8DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA228&lpg=PA228&dq=%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83&source=bl&ots=wC6lFdabcl&sig=ACfU3U0B2Yt_cnLeLpq3hcNMsnk-8zQC7w&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYxZz9-6HsAhVppYsKHX7SCocQ6AEwBnoECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83&f=false)

**Дополнение**

Нечасто, конечно, но сочетание *рассержен* (кем?) *мной* (или кем-то другим) встречается в литературе ([Песни трубадуров](https://imwerden.de/pdf/pesni_trubadurov_1979__ocr.pdf). Перевод А. Наймана, стр. 108):

> Ею был я удержан от всякой любовной напасти,
> **И не мною рассержен** опять дух мучительной страсти,
> Ею в прах я повержен, палим, раздираем на части,
> И чтоб сердцем своим овладеть, подходящей нет снасти...

P. S. Оба приведенных правила — это правила одного автора, Д. Розенталя, но в одном — "рассержен кем-чем", а в другом — только "чем".

Answer (score 0):

**Творительный падеж**. Я рассержен глупой выходкой. Значение выражения: меня рассердила глупая выходка. Это наиболее нормативное употребление. Также в творительном падеже допустимо такое употребление: я рассержен лютой злобой. Значение выражения: я испытываю лютую злобу в результате того, что рассержен.

**Винительный падеж**. Рассержен на глупую выходку. Значение выражения: меня злит этот поступок, глупая выходка. Выражение более кривое, но допустимое. Нечто подобное есть в психологии, когда рекомендуют осуждать не человека, а его поступок. "Твой поступок меня сердит" (а не ты сам).

Какую из двух фраз выбрать? Зависит от контекста. В творительном падеже мы можем подразумевать, что сердимся на человека, совершившего глупую выходку. В винительном падеже мы уже конкретно заостряем внимание, что злимся на выходку, как бы исключая возможность того, что мы злимся на человека.

**Дательный падеж**. Рассержен глупой выходке. Такой синтаксис не нормативен. Слышать такое случается: "Рассержен неудаче" и пр. Но это неверное словоупотребление. Дательный падеж указывает направление действия, а не его причину. "Я не дам глупой выходке меня рассердить". С употреблением дательного падежа можно переформулировать изначальную фразу в близкую по смыслу и нормативную: "Глупой выходке удалось меня рассердить". Это пассивный залог, что не очень красиво и не особо литературно, но нормативно.

"Рассердиться неуместной шуткой". **Творительный падеж.** Из-за инфинитива теряется нормативность выражения. Вместо причины "неуместная шутка" становится способом проявления злости, что неправильно. Можно рассердиться лютой злобой.

"Рассердиться на неуместную шутку". **Винительный падеж.** Нормативно. Именно так и говорят.

"Рассердиться неуместной шутке". **Дательный падеж.** Не нормативно, но "в народе" такое кривое выражение услышать можно. В литературе допустимо в рамках стилизации прямой речи, но в грамотной письменной речи это будет ошибкой.

Comment: А можно сказать: "графин, полный водой". Или всё всё-таки нужно говорить только: "графин, полный воды"?

Comment: Здесь не решают домашние задания. Если вы хотите, чтобы вам дали ответ, создайте отдельную тему под новый вопрос и изложите свои соображения. Как минимум, напишите сами, считаете ли вы, можно ли так сказать. В рамках данного обсуждения вам следует либо уточнить что-то по текущему вопросу, либо принять, если ответ вас устроил.

Comment: @Исломбек   Эту тему можно посмотреть по ссылке: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462182/Можно-ли-считать-устаревшей-форму-полный-полон-водой

Answer (score 0):

Желательно говорить так:

1. Он рассердился **на меня за неуместную шутку**, он рассердился **на себя за глупую выходку**.
2. *Он рассержен **моей неуместной шуткой**, он рассержен **своей глупой выходкой**.*

Сравнить: Шутка рассердила его. Он рассержен шуткой (в пассивной форме используется Т.п.).

**Пояснение**

Таким образом, мы различаем кто (одушевленный предмет) и чем (неодушевленный предмет) рассердил человека.

Нельзя сказать: он рассержен (кем?) мной. **Нежелательно** (хотя иногда  в некоторых сочетаниях и допускается) говорить: он рассержен (на что?) на мою неуместную шутку, потому что неодушевленные существительные  могут восприниматься как одушевленные. Тогда это будет выглядеть как **стилистическая погрешность**.

Дательный падеж в таких формах не используется.

И вывод: к словарным рекомендациям, приведенным в одном из ответов,  в данном случае **приходится относиться очень осторожно.**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (для тех, кто голосует за Розенталя)**

Итак, все верят Розенталю (или его редакторам) и за него голосуют. А Розенталь нам говорит: *рассердиться на кого-что — рассержен кем-чем*.

Я рассердился (на что?) на свою глупую выходку. Я рассержен (кем?) своим другом.

Ничего, нормально, всем нравится? Или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: Что значит "Он рассердиться на меня за неуместную шутку"?

Comment: Я думаю, что  ничего не значит.  Редактировала текст и не всё исправила.